# how to scale a HTML background video

Tags: html, css

I've got my HTML video as a background with some overlay on it, but the issue I am running into is scaling the video how I want. I have a set height on my `.videoSection`, but when the browser is shrunk to small, instead of scaling and cutting off the ends of the video as I would like, it just re-scales to a smaller overall size while leaving white space underneath the video. Hope I am being clear enough. Here's my HTML:

```
<section class="topInfo1">
        <div class="videoSection">
            <video id="video-elem" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted">
                <source src='/CMS_Static/Uploads/313864614C6F6F/C0071_1-1.mp4' type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class="videoOverlay">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row text-center">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                        <h1>Marketing the Boating and Marine Industry Through Video</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
                        <a class="btn topInfoBtn btn-block" href="/services">Learn More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

and the CSS

```
.videoSection {
        position: relaltive;
        width: 100%;
        height: 650px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #video-elem {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .videoOverlay {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
        position: absolute;
        top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checkout out [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fullscreen_video.asp), and it looks like the key styles on the `<video>` element are:

```
#video-elem {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

However in your case it looks like you want a video header only (as opposed to full screen fixed video, so you'd want to have:

```
position: absolute;
```

[Here's a demo](https://codepen.io/zaggamok/pen/YJoXNK?editors=0100) I cooked up.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem I am having with this is now my video is full height and is not at the 650px I set in the .videoSection.

Comment: w3schools?! Ew!

Comment: @FinsUp I see what you mean. I've edited the demo with a slightly different approach using flexbox to center content and, I think, respect the 650px height requirement at all screen resolutions.

Comment: This keeps the size of the section set at 650px like I would like, but the video is resizing to its original aspect ratio, filling the rest of the area in the section with the red background color. Basically what I am essentially looking to do is find a way to break the aspect ratio of the video so it can become narrower as the browser shrinks.

Comment: @FinsUp if I understand correctly, you'd like the entire video to display at all screen resolutions (never overflow). You'd also like to maintain 650px height at all screen resolutions. Is that correct?

Comment: Picture a css background image instead of my video set to background-position: center and height: 600px. This is exactly what I would like to achieve but instead with the video. When browser width is shrunk narrower, the right and left side of the image begin to cut off, while staying at the same height.

Comment: Hmm, as far as I can tell, the demo does this -- I am seeing no red and the height is reported to be 650px at any res. Maybe a browser thing, I am using Chrome currently and I have not used any vendor prefixes. Or maybe I didn't save, would you mind trying the link again?

Comment: Ahh actually just got it working. I forgot to add margin: 0; and padding: 0; to the body. Works perfect. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

CSS:

```
video {
 object-fit: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 width:100%;
 height: 100%; 
 position: absolute; 
 top: 0; 
 left: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<video muted="" playsinline="" autoplay=""  loop="" preload="auto">
  <source src="/CMS_Static/Uploads/313864614C6F6F/C0071_1-1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: hmm. Tried it and messed around with it, but the height of my video is still at full.

Comment: @FinsUp Have you tried with `height:auto` or `vh` unit ?

Comment: Yes. height:auto works, but that sets the height to the size of the video. I'd like to have it set at 600px.

Comment: Maybe also add max-height: 600px.

Comment: ah works but still not as id like. It scales the whole video to a smaller size, as I'd like to just crop the edges of the video out and essentially have a changing aspect ratio of the video instead of keeping the same aspect ratio and shrinking it down.